# Leetcode 17 question on the python dictionary key issue

Tags: python, dictionary

When I was doing the question 17 of leetcode, it was described as:
Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent. Return the answer in any order."

Then the dictionary for all the letters corresponded to the number can be described as:

```
n_dict = {"2":["a", "b", "c"], 
             "3":["d", "e", "f"], 
             "4":["g", "h", "i"], 
             "5":["j", "k", "l"], 
             "6":["m", "n", "o"], 
             "7":["p", "q", "r", "s"], 
             "8":["t", "u", "v"], 
             "9":["w", "x", "y", "z"]}
```

My solution was like:

```
self.output = []

    def helper(number):
        if not number: return
        if self.output:
            times = len(self.output)
            #print(n_dict[number[0]])
            for _ in range(0, times):
                item = self.output.pop(0)
                for char in n_dict[number[0]]:
                    self.output.append(item+char)
            return
        else:
            self.output = n_dict[number[0]]
        helper(number[1:])
        return
    
    helper(digits)
    return self.output
```

This works well for "23", "567", "3267" and other non-repeated digits combinations.
However, when the input became "22" or even "232", the running time just went crazy, then I tried to figure out why, and a very strange thing happend. I insert the print command on the line above, and the output is something below:

```
['b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'ab']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab', 'aac']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab', 'aac', 'aaab']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab', 'aac', 'aaab', 'aaac']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab', 'aac', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaaab']
['b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'aab', 'aac', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaaab', 'aaaac']
```

This means n_dict["2"] only contains ["b", "c"] rather than ["a", "b", "c"]. Other than that, the for loop became infinite rather than on the range of the length n_dict["2"].
Does anyone know how did this happened? Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, you're removing the item from the list, instead of just iterating through the elements of the list.   Next time you come to that list, it won't be there.

Comment: A better solution might be to use `itertools.product(*list_of_lists)`.  For example, for "233", call `itertools.product(*[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["d", "e", "f"]])`.  For each tuple you get from this, you'll need to `"".join` it into a string.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I think that is the reason for the strange behavior. The list has been changed due to the pop.

Answer (score 1):

- There might be a bug in the algorithm.
- This would pass on LeetCode similarly using a dictionary:

```
class Solution:
    def letterCombinations(self, digits):
        if digits == '':
            return []
        d = {
        '2': 'abc',
        '3': 'def',
        '4': 'ghi',
        '5': 'jkl',
        '6': 'mno',
        '7': 'pqrs',
        '8': 'tuv',
        '9': 'wxyz'
        }
        res = ['']
        for digit in digits:
            temp = []
            for r in res:
                for item in d[digit]:
                    temp.append(r + item)
                res = temp
        return res
```

Comment: Thank you, Emma. Your answer really works for this question.